# Question on memoization issue - BestSum Problem implementation in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming, memoization

Problem statement - Write a bestSum(targetSum, array_numbers) function that takes in TargetSum and an array of numbers as arguments and returns an array containing shortest combination of numbers that add up to exactly the target sum)

When I am solving this problem without memoization, I am getting the correct set of outputs. However, when I am trying to solve with memoization I am getting incorrect results.

The codes and outputs (with and without memoization) are below. Can't figure out what I am missing or doing wrong here on the 2nd part (i.e with memoization).

***Without Memoization***

```
def bestSum(m, bestSumlist):
    if m == 0:
        return []
    if m < 0:
        return None
    
    shortest_comb = None
    
    for i in bestSumlist:
        remainder = m - i
        remainder_combination = bestSum(remainder, bestSumlist)
        if remainder_combination != None:
            remainder_combination.append(i) 
            combination = remainder_combination
            if shortest_comb == None or len(shortest_comb) > len(combination):
                shortest_comb = combination
            
    return shortest_comb
```

***Outputs***

print(bestSum(7, [5,3,4,7]))

> **[7]**

print(bestSum(8, [2,3,5]))

> **[5, 3]**

print(bestSum(8, [1,4,5]))

> **[4, 4]**

print(bestSum(8, [2,3]))

> **[3, 3, 2]**

print(bestSum(8, [2,3]))

> **[3, 3, 2]**

print(bestSum(7, [2,4]))

> **None**

***With Memoization*** (this is where I am having issues)

```
def bestSum_memo(m, bestSumlist):
    if m in memo_dict:
        return memo_dict[m]
    if m == 0:
        return []
    if m < 0:
        return None
    
    shortest_comb = None
    
    for i in bestSumlist:
        remainder = m - i
        remainder_combination = bestSum_memo(remainder, bestSumlist)
        if remainder_combination != None:
            remainder_combination.append(i) 
            combination = remainder_combination
            if shortest_comb == None or len(shortest_comb) > len(combination):
                shortest_comb = combination        
           
    memo_dict[m] = shortest_comb   
    return shortest_comb
```

***Outputs***

memo_dict={}

print(bestSum_memo(7, [5,3,4,7]))

> **[7]** (this is correct)

memo_dict={}

print(bestSum_memo(8, [2,3,5]))

> **[5, 3]** (this is correct)

memo_dict={}

print(bestSum_memo(8, [1,4,5]))

> **[4, 1, 4]** (this is wrong)

memo_dict={}

print(bestSum_memo(8, [2,3]))

> **[3, 3, 2, 2, 3]** (this is wrong)

memo_dict={}

print(bestSum_memo(8, [2,3]))

> **[3, 3, 2, 2, 3]** (this is wrong)

memo_dict={}

print(bestSum_memo(7, [2,4]))

> **None** (this is correct)

Comment: Memorization only works with *immutable* return values / pure functions. Your algorithm using `remainder_combination.append(i)` conflicts with this.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi - Ok, got it. Is there a way to fix this in Python implementation. Appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on MisterMiyagi's comment, I was able to solve it.

In this solution below, I am copying the list to a temp list and altering that one instead of mutating the original list and that takes care of the issue I was having earlier. Thank you!!

***Code -***

```
import copy
def bestSum_memo(m, bestSumlist):
    if m in memo_dict:
        return memo_dict[m]
    if m == 0:
        return []
    if m < 0:
        return None
    
    shortest_comb = None
    
    for i in bestSumlist:
        remainder = m - i
        remainder_combination = bestSum_memo(remainder, bestSumlist)
        if remainder_combination != None:
            remainder_combination_copy = copy.deepcopy(remainder_combination)
            remainder_combination_copy.append(i) 
            combination = remainder_combination_copy
            if shortest_comb == None or len(shortest_comb) > len(combination):
                shortest_comb = combination        
           
    memo_dict[m] = shortest_comb   
    return shortest_comb
```

Comment: As an alternative, use a ``tuple`` and do ``combination = remainder_combination  + (i,)``. This will create a new tuple without changing the old one.